# Pagination is not working in static website

Tags: jquery, html

I have used jquery pagination in static website but it s not displaying the pagination links tried wih the following code.

HTML:

```
<div class="pagination">
                <div id="blog" class="well">

                    <h3>Daily Newspaper</h3>
                    <small>Posted on <strong>December 14, 2017</strong></small>
                    <img src="images/Blog1.jpg" alt="check" class="img-responsive"/>

                    <hr>
                    <h3>Daily Newspaper</h3>
                    <small>Posted on <strong>December 18, 2017</strong></small>
                    <img src="images/Blog1.jpg" alt="check" class="img-responsive"/>                        
                    <hr>
                    <h3>Daily Newspapers</h3>
                    <small>Posted on <strong>December 14, 2017</strong></small>
                    <img src="images/Blog1.jpg" alt="check" class="img-responsive"/>

                    <hr>
                    <h3>Daily Newspapers</h3>
                    <small>Posted on <strong>December 18, 2017</strong></small>
                    <img src="images/Blog1.jpg" alt="check" class="img-responsive"/>                        
                    <hr>

                </div>
                </div>
```

This is my fiddle link where i have added my script as well

https://jsfiddle.net/ua5a55kq/4/

Comment: instead, why don't you use dataTable.

Comment: Maybe becuase you have `<div class="pagination">` but in the jquery you call `$('.pagnation')` Also you would have to wrap your "news"

Comment: You dont have any objects with the class `newsbox` neither, Please update your code.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i have changed the class pagination spelling mistake in script but also the same

Comment: @user9131066 update your fiddle link with the updated code

Comment: Tried with different codes for pagination but not working

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen my fiddle update link https://jsfiddle.net/ua5a55kq/18/

Comment: Again, as I said, you have no elements with the class `newsbox`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen can you please update in my code it will be more helpful

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i have updated my fiddle with newsbox but still not working this is the updated lik https://jsfiddle.net/ua5a55kq/21/

Comment: Here you go, the problem was the jquery version https://jsfiddle.net/ua5a55kq/30/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks a lot issue has been resolved